# Compiling x264 with mp4 support

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, mp4, x264

I need `x264` for my project.
I have one at `/opt/local/bin/x264`, but when I execute the following command:

```
x264 --qpfile cuepoints.qp --output output.mp4 input.mp4
```

it says:

`x264 [error]: not compiled with MP4 output support`

I decided to compile `x264` from the source. I downloaded the source from http://www.videolan.org/ (git://git.videolan.org/x264.git).
Now I do:

```
cd x264
./configure --enable-mp4-output
```

And x264 says:

```
Unknown option --enable-mp4-output, ignored
```

And indeed, if I open `configure` file, there is no such option.

Finally, I could find compiled x264 with mp4 support (see [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osx264/files/x264_old_compiles_for_snow-leopard/)), but it is 3 years old and I need one more for Windows.

Do you know if `x264` have dropped mp4 support, or I need to use a different option to compile it?

Comment: on a mobile device currently so can't properly check but from memory you need to download and compile GPAC then copy output into the x264 git folder before compiling in order to enable mp4. Doom9 / Doom10 forums might be a better place to look for specifics on the topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `--enable-mp4-output` option. MP4 support is automatically detected, but [l-smash](http://code.google.com/p/l-smash/) or gpac are required.

For a script that might compile x264 see [HOWTO: x264](http://englanders.us/~jason/howtos.php?howto=x264).
For another example see [Compiling X264 on Ubuntu](http://www.curlybrace.com/words/2008/05/15/compiling-x264-on-ubuntu/).
Also see the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).

Answer (score 1):

You can install x264 with mp4 output support on macOS with brew:

```
brew install x264 --with-l-smash
```

Comment: This gives me `Warning: x264: this formula has no --with-l-smash option so it will be ignored!`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://astrataro.wordpress.com/category/encode/x264/ which provides modified builds with mp4 and audio enabled.